# Should character limit for comments exclude link URLs?

Tags: feature-request, comments, character-limit

The character limit on comments is 600 characters. This seems enough, but providing useful comments often involves including links, which can be rather long. The length of links is counted towards the overall length of the comment, in which case 600 characters can be very restrictive. If you include three links of length 100 characters each (not uncommon), your comment limit is down to 300 characters.

I suggest that only the link text would count towards the length of the comment. For example, this comment:

```
Use the [groupingBy method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-).
```

which renders as:

> Use the [groupingBy method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-).

should count as 26 characters long, instead of 198 characters long.

Comment: This has definitely already been asked before. I'll go look for that question...

Comment: Remarkably, I can't find it. I could have sworn that this was already asked...

Comment: There are multiple Meta.SE duplicates, but no Meta.SO duplicates (As far as I can tell): [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93102/159034), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137036/159034), [3](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52976/159034), [4](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156667/159034)

Comment: @Alex as Kevin said, it was already asked on MSE, like great many other questions here on MSO.

Comment: I support this. Sometimes when I want to clarify a point or ask a question most of my comment gets gobbled up by the url length and it usally makes the comment less friendly to read.

Comment: Note: nobody says you cannot post more than one comment in a row... If you have to post multiple links and you need more characters, just post 2 comments.

Comment: @Bakuriu This is what I do now. But it is not a solution. Then a comment is no longer self-contained. Plus there is the possibility that someone will comment just in between the two comments, which breaks fluency.

Comment: I'm definitely sympathetic to the sentiment that link URLs should not count toward the character limit. However, as a practical matter, I think 600 characters is actually quite enough. I'm pretty sure it wasn't always that high. For all I know, they increased it specifically to accommodate links. In any case, I think it's reasonable for the system to discourage long comments.

Comment: @JohnY I would rather have 400 chars and not counting the URLs, than 600 chars and counting the URLs. Increasing the limit to accommodate links is a poor man's workaround, not a principled solution.

Comment: @JohnY Your comment, btw, is 378 characters without any links or formatting, so I don't think 600 characters is _that_ much.

Comment: This has been problematic for me quite often - suggesting 2 links and asking a question/clarification almost never fits

Comment: @TomasMikula: I know it was long. I was going to add "like this one" at the end, but by the time I thought of it, the editing grace period was over.

Comment: @TomasMikula: You keep talking about a principled solution. One of the points that seems to keep passing you by is that practicality often trumps principles. If something is "good enough" and already in production, then the bar to fix/change it is higher than it might be, judging purely from principles. I'm not saying your idea definitely doesn't meet the bar. I'm just saying the bar might be higher than you think it is, or higher than you think it should be. Personally, I'd be happy if links didn't count, but I wouldn't be upset if they left things as they are. So +0 from me.

Comment: @JohnY Wherever the bar is, if this is something that improves the status quo, it should be kept track of. Standard task prioritization applies.

Comment: This is not something unique to SO so should be asked on MSE, oh wait... it already has! @shog9 Shouldn't this be closed or at least migrated?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is already covered multiple time on MSE, this question should be removed or migrated.

Comment: This looks to be the original - [Formatting should not count towards the character limit on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/formatting-should-not-count-towards-the-character-limit-on-comments). Have also flagged the associated questions on MSE.

Comment: @Lankymart It is definitely not off-topic. It is a duplicate at worst. Then go ahead and mark it as a duplicate. **Oh wait, there is no duplicate!** MSE is a different site than MSO (with a different login, for example). Your comment is not so different than saying "Close this question because it has already been asked at Yahoo answers."

Comment: @Lankymart Also importantly, the question you link to does _not_ cover the issue raised here. It covers formatting, which adds a constant factor of character overhead (the constant being quite small). My question talks about links, which can add an arbitrary character overhead.

Comment: @TomasMikula There is no difference. MSE is the parent site for all SE sites including SO. This question relates to a [meta-tag:feature-request] that has already been requested and in more detail. There are four questions on MSE take your pick *(Kevin's [earlier comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286306/should-character-limit-for-comments-not-include-link-urls?noredirect=1#comment156408_286306))*. The other three I've already flagged as duplicates of the one I linked, which was originally [meta-tag:status-declined].

Comment: @Lankymart There _is_ a difference. You are suggesting I create an account on a different site. FWIW, I do not have an account on SE. I did get the message that the issue might be better addressed there, but I do not agree that it is off-topic or duplicate here.

Comment: @TomasMikula Yes you do *(even if you don't know it)*, like I said SE is the parent of all SE sites. What you have *(should have)* is an SE account that is used for logging in to any site in the SE family. Every new SE site I logon to requests my SE login details. Clicking on your profile in SO or MSO will show in the top right corner `Network Profile` which is a link to your SE profile.

Comment: @Lankymart Now this discussion is getting off-topic. I do get all that. My point was rather subtle: technically, they are different (although linked) accounts. When I try to login to MSE, it says "You are about to create a new account on Meta Stack Exchange ...". Although it does also say "We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites," it is technically a different account.

Comment: Questions on other sites are useful as references but not something that requires action here, @lank

Comment: Related: [Why do emph-, code-, bold-, etc-marks count toward comment-length?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291788/why-do-emph-code-bold-etc-marks-count-toward-comment-length)

Comment: related: [discourage url shorteners in comments: don't add link's href size to the total comment size](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293/137096)

Comment: 2 years later, neither declined or implemented. Slipped through the cracks? C'mon...

Comment: Just ran in the same issue. Using a lengthy URL just takes me space and I have to split my comment into two. A link should simply just count as a single char.. But definitely not the length of the URL itself.

Comment: Ran into the same issue . Need to post this link https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/default-encryption/?utm_medium=et&utm_source=google.com%2Fcloud&utm_campaign=resources&utm_content=resource_card#data_encryption_keys_key_encryption_keys_and_googles_key_management_service . Ate half my capacity and has to split the comment and felt not good as the comment is not self contained.

Answer (score 20):

From the community's point of view, I can't think of a single good argument in favor of the current system, where URLs underneath unobtrusive blue text count toward the character limit.

I just posted a comment that could have used at least 5 more links. The comment was only indirectly related to OP's question, so it didn't warrant a new answer. The nature of the comment was nevertheless informative, and further reading was suggested (with more black letters than I had hoped).

Constructive link sharing is knowledge sharing, which should never be discouraged on this site (in my opinion). Comment threads are valuable resources for me, and I appreciate it when others take the time to include links. I click on them frequently.

From a technical point of view, I can think of several possible reasons why URLs count toward the limit, the first and most valid of which being "nobody ever got around to implementing it."

Answer (score -21):

As comments are not given the same gravitas as questions, I think it's perfectly acceptable to use link shorteners within them. So

```
Use the [groupingBy method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-).
```

becomes

```
Use the [groupingBy method](http://is.gd/q8sOUK).
```

I would **not** suggest using link shorteners in questions or answers though as they're just adding another layer which can rot away and hence reduce the usefulness of the post.

Comment: While this is a valid workaround, I think the point of the OP still stands and there shouldn't be any need for a link shortener

Comment: URL shorteners are off-limits [over at Security.SE](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/162/9831), but the ban was rejected [at Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64450/159034). It's not something I'd recommend, but it does avoid the character limit.

Comment: @KevinBrown Maybe there needs to be a StackExchange shortener!

Comment: @dav_i That's the solution Twitter ended up going with: implement a site-specific shortener.

Comment: While link shorteners are a viable workaround, I do not consider it a solution. Having the real URL is useful: it provides some additional information before actually clicking on the link. In the made up example above, it tells me, before clicking, that it points to official Oracle Java API, as opposed to, e.g. some third party library. I would accept a solution similar to Twitter's, where it replaces your URL with a shortened t.co/... version that consumes 14 characters for each link, but they still display the original target of the link in the tweet.

Comment: I'd discourage link shortners. I'd preferr to see a second comment with the link rather than a obscured URL.