# Why do emph-, code-, bold-, etc-marks count toward comment-length?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

Why do the code marks (``), the cursive marks (_) and so on count toward the length of to comment on stackoverflow?

It made me have to delete them all in order to fit the max-length of a comment. It's a bit of work, but maybe this could be changed?

A related question I found here about URLs:
[Should character limit for comments not include link URLs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286306/should-character-limit-for-comments-not-include-link-urls)

but in contrast to URLs, I can't use a shortener for the marks.

Comment: Then perhaps it's a good indicator that you should make your comment briefer.

Comment: @ace: It fitted after I removed them all. And I even had symbols left. But I removed all for consistency.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52976/259700

Comment: Ok. May I be so bold as to suggest, nay, let me reword it to: *strongly* suggest, as the word "bold" (be assured it is not to mean **bold**) may not carry enough *gravitas* for the situation under discussion, to perhaps consider keeping your reflections and ruminations, cogitations, contemplations, and considerations, terse rather than verbose, as is warranted by both *nature* and *intent* of a humble *comment* field.

Comment: Or, you could just *split the text across two comments*..

Comment: The current character limit is 500 characters. *Perhaps* the SE team wanted a 450 character limit, but increased it to 500 to allow for formatting characters ;-)

Comment: Ok, I understand. Would it at this point be appropriate to delete my question?

Comment: @dingalapadum I would say it isn't, as it has an upvoted answer and could be useful.

Answer (score 10):

If your comment is so long that it doesn't fit or has so much emphasised that it doesn't fit then I'd say that's a good indication that the comment shouldn't be posted.

Comments, as we keep saying, are meant for transitory remarks to get clarification from the OP (which is edited into the post **not** left as a comment), point out errors in code, point out broken links etc. None of these should require you to write an essay and none should require much, if any, emphasis.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, at all. The question isn't "should it be a problem for the user?", the question is "why?".

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: You've got *six hundred characters to use!*  You can't make it work, give or take an underscore or two?

Comment: @RobertHarvey maybe, maybe yes, maybe no, but that's not the question. You and Chris appear to be missing the point. `Why do the code marks (``) count toward the length of to comment?` The question is why. It's either a bug, or a design decision. By SE's standards I'm going to assume a design decision. In which case, what's the reason behind the decision?

Comment: @JayMee: You don't ask how to replace a hubcap when the engine needs rebuilding.  There is such a thing as "relative importance," and this issue isn't important enough to ask why.

Comment: Says who? It's at the reader's discretion as to whether this is of importance or not. Judging by the up-votes, there are a few people that disagree with you. If you feel this question is not important, that's perfectly fine, but it doesn't mean you can claim to be addressing it with an answer that's irrelevant.

Comment: I never made that claim.

Comment: That's fair. Chris did, though, which is why I commented.

Comment: *[shrug]*  Software developers wonder why you have to jiggle the toilet handle to get the water to stop flowing; meanwhile, the house is burning down.  It's both a blessing and a curse; we have an incredible grasp of detail, but a remarkable inability to focus on what is important.  *This isn't important.*

Comment: It's just a question. Answering a question more or less trivial than others doesn't necessarily detract from that which is important. There are many, many questions on StackExchange of varying importance. Answering those and also giving important topics some time isn't mutually exclusive.

Comment: If we believed that, then we wouldn't have a close system, as every question, no matter how trivial, unclear or broad, could be given equal weight.  Note that Shog basically provided the same answer that Chris did.

Comment: I never made the claim that they should be given equal weight, or that clarity didn't matter. Unclear/broad questions should be closed. I'm saying some questions are more important than others, but that doesn't mean the less important shouldn't be answered. This question I'd say is rather trivial, but it doesn't warrant inaccurate answers or, rather, answers that don't even address the question.

Comment: I would @ reply, but I'm on mobile and it doesn't work. @JayMee my answer is essentially the same as Shog's. Given the length you have it's not deemed important enough to write and support the code required to ignore these special characters. If you find yourself writing an essay put it in an answer.

Comment: So your answer, then, is that it's not worth the development and maintenance effort. That's an answer, that's all I was getting at.

Answer (score 7):

We could do crazy Twitter-style readjustments of the maximum length based on exceptions... But honestly, that's pretty confusing and shouldn't be necessary; 600 characters is a lot more than 280. If you can't say what you need to in 600 characters, maybe use less formatting... Or just write an answer and link to it.

#### See also: [Don't count non-printing characters, HTML comments or other content not displayed toward minimum character requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137006/dont-count-non-printing-characters-html-comments-or-other-content-not-displaye)

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely can't shorten your comment without making a pig's ear of it, just split it in two comments. It's not ideal, but it sure beats fouling up your links with shorteners, or giving up on inline code formatting.