# Converting link comment into a standard format

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, markdown

I have seen many comments of the type `<just a link here>`. I don't know how useful this feature would be, but can we instead standardise these types of comments and change them to `take a look at [this](<whatever link>) link` or `Take a look at [<Title of the link>](<whatever link>)`?

Comment: Why would this be useful?

Comment: Well, yeah, I read that. But the whole idea behind feature requests is that you only propose them when you actually think they'd be useful.

Comment: I just thought it might be more... `professional looking`; that's all

Comment: Sidenote: please don't use `code block` for *emphasizing*. Misuse of `code block` can be considered as formatting abuse.

Comment: Raw URLs without any title can be a bit annoying, but the worst cases are when people post those giant Google search result URLs. But I guess that only happens in actual questions or answers, not comments, since those URLs are so huge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not useful.

First of all, comments have a limited length. Adding a title or even the mark-up bits can push it over the length limit. There are feature requests that request that the length limit shouldn't apply to markdown but that has not yet been honored in the 6 to 8 weeks that FR has been up.

Secondly I'm not confident I want this to be the default behavior. I can imagine cases where the title isn't all that descriptive. Now I have to fiddle with markdown after all to make it **NOT** do its standard thing.

Third reason I dislike this is the fact that the title needs to come from somewhere. Either my computer or even worse the servers of SE need to fetch that page, parse the html received, find the head and title and get that string, put in the markdown. That is assuming the site exists, and serves html at that endpoint. I leave out the option where users offer *fake* domains as an example only to find later the domain hosts content of disputable content with revealed by its title.

Fourth and final argument is the professional looking aspect. If the looks of a link in a comment are important the link should probably be part of the post, not a comment. Comments are after all only post-it notes with a non-permanent character.

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks?! More like 6 to 8 centuries. LOL!

Comment: "First of all, comments have a limited length" - aren't those magic thingies (i.e. `[so]`) exempt from length restrictions? It's 4 characters, and counts as 4 characters while editing, but inserts a longer text afterwards.

Comment: @Zoe Yes, but regular links are not. For example: `Check [this article](https://SomeWebsite.com/q=VeryLongQuery)` will leave you very little space for the rest of your comment. I've been waiting forever for [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286306/8967612) as indicated above.

Comment: @41686d6564 no, but if it automatically converts `https://SomeWebsite.com/q=VeryLongQuery` to `[Whatever Title Here](https://SomeWebsite.com/q=VeryLongQuery)` similarly to magic links or whatever, the additional markdown would be exempt from the count, and therefore wouldn't be a problem. But again, this would be solved with the good 'ol markdown doesn't count towards the limit FR, so it wouldn't really be necessary to implement this if that got implemented instead